# How to save posta code in custom zip_code field in sales_order table in magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer

I have created a custom `zip_code` field in the sales order table. I want to save the postal code in my custom `zip_code` field after place an order.

please check the below code

> events.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_save_after">
        <observer name="magento_orderevent_create" instance="khoaln\Sales\Observer\SalesOrderPlaceAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> SalesOrderPlaceAfter.php code

```
 <?php
namespace Khoaln\Sales\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesOrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $orderDetailData = getPostcode();
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $order->setData('zip_code', json_encode($orderDetailData));
            $order->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sales_model_service_quote_submit_before` instead of `sales_order_save_after`.

You can try below code:

```
 <?php
namespace Khoaln\Sales\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SalesOrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        try {
            $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
            $billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
            $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
            $orderDetailData = getPostcode();
            $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
            $order->setData('zip_code',  $shippingAddress->getData('postcode'));
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            error_log($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you amit@Amit